# pcl ros lib not working properly

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[planefitting-2] process has died [pid 20119, exit code -4, cmd /home/mritunjay/ros-workspace/planesegmentationTutorial/bin/planefitting __name:=planefitting __log:=/home/mritunjay/.ros/log/674f554a-c7c1-11e2-8a81-e091532ec99a/planefitting-2.log].
log file: /home/mritunjay/.ros/log/674f554a-c7c1-11e2-8a81-e091532ec99a/planefitting-2*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63736/pcl-ros-lib-not-working-properly/) by [Mrit91](https://answers.ros.org/users/5003/mrit91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's likely this issue: https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/10

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mrit91](https://answers.ros.org/users/5003/mrit91/) on 2013-06-27**:
Yeah! I had installed a 64 bit OS on a 32 bit hardware. Thnx for answering.